# Error while sending email using Firebase cloud functions with Vue Js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I was trying to send email using Firebase cloud function from a form submitted Data, and it doesn't send it at all.

My function code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors')({
  origin: '*'
})

admin.initializeApp();

/**
 * Here we're using Gmail to send 
 */
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'password'
  }
});

exports.sendEmail = functions.https.onCall((contact, context) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    const dest = req.body.dest

    console.log(dest)

    const mailOptions = {
      from: `Contact AET  ${contact.email}`,
      to: dest,
      subject: "AET Website Message ", // Subject line
      html: `
        <div 
            style="padding: 10px; font-family:Gadaj; border: 2px solid #eee; border-radius: 10px ">
          <p style="font-size: 15px">You have a new message request</p>
            <h2>Contact Details</h2>
            <ul style="list-style-type: none">
               <li>Name: ${contact.name}</li>
               <li>Email: ${contact.email}</li>
            </ul>
            <h2>Message</h2>
            <p style="font-size: 16px;">${contact.message}</p>
            <img src="https://images.prod.meredith.com/product/fc8754735c8a9b4aebb786278e7265a5/1538025388228/l/rick-and-morty-pickle-rick-sticker" />
        </div>
   `
    };

    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err)
      }
      return console.log(`Message sent to ${info.messageId}`)
    })
  })

})
```

and then i hooked it up in my FrontEnd Like so

```
sendMessage() {
      if (this.$refs.formEmail.validate()) {
        this.loading = true;
        const createMessage = {
          name: this.name,
          email: this.email,
          message: this.message
        };
        const sendEmail = functions.httpsCallable("sendEmail");
        sendEmail(createMessage)
          .then(res => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log(res.data);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
    }
```

I gets this back as the error:

```
 Error: Error: INTERNAL
    at new HttpsErrorImpl (index.cjs.js?001a:58)
    at _errorForResponse (index.cjs.js?001a:153)
    at Service.eval (index.cjs.js?001a:538)
    at step (tslib.es6.js?9ab4:99)
    at Object.eval [as next] (tslib.es6.js?9ab4:80)
    at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js?9ab4:70)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: FYI: If you have updates to your question, don't add a comment.  You can instead edit the question directly with the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing the following cannot work:

```
exports.sendEmail = functions.https.onCall((contact, context) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {...});
});
```

You are mixing [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and [HTTPS ones](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) (which take the Node.js express `req` and `res` as parameters). `req` and `res` will not have any value and therefore `dest` will be null.

I would kindly suggest that you study the Callable Cloud Functions documentation.

The following should do the trick (not tested):

```
exports.sendEmail = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    try {

        const dest = data.email

        console.log(dest)

        const mailOptions = {
            from: `Contact AET  ${contact.email}`,
            to: dest,
            subject: "AET Website Message ", // Subject line
            html: `
        <div 
            style="padding: 10px; font-family:Gadaj; border: 2px solid #eee; border-radius: 10px ">
          <p style="font-size: 15px">You have a new message request</p>
            <h2>Contact Details</h2>
            <ul style="list-style-type: none">
               <li>Name: ${contact.name}</li>
               <li>Email: ${contact.email}</li>
            </ul>
            <h2>Message</h2>
            <p style="font-size: 16px;">${contact.message}</p>
            <img src="https://images.prod.meredith.com/product/fc8754735c8a9b4aebb786278e7265a5/1538025388228/l/rick-and-morty-pickle-rick-sticker" />
        </div>
   `
        };

        await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);

        return null;

    } catch (error) {

       // See the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors

    }

})
```

---

Note that we do `const dest = data.email`, since there is no `dest` element in the `createMessage` object you use to call the CF.

---

You may also study this sample: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/email-users/functions/index.js

Comment: i have tried it sir, thanks so much, i receive this in my console:

 ``Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8``

Comment: The Email got sent sir, everything is working fine, but i got null from the data

``{data: null}
data: null ``

Same as the Mail The data passed return ``null``

Comment: Where do you get `data = null`? the `data` parameter of the Cloud Function? `functions.https.onCall(async (data, context)`

Comment: yes sir... but it seams i didn't import sendEmail Function well... i was using this relative path which is wrong. ``import { functions } from "../firebase";``

The questions is how do i import that function

Comment: You know i use exports.sendEmail... how do i import that function and use it in my component

Comment: You know i use exports.sendEmail... how do i import that function and use it in my component from the functions folder

Comment: You need to share all the files of your Vue.js app that are implied in the Firebase config. Or you could align your code on the following [Github repo](https://github.com/savvyapps/SAVuegram/tree/master/src), which does work.

Comment: Let me Edit the question, so you will see how i imported it

Comment: Thank you so so much... instead of me doing, 

``const createMessage = {
          name: this.formData.name,
          email: this.formData.email,
          message: this.formData.message
        };``

I was referencing an empty V-model.

``const createMessage = {
          name: this.name,
          email: this.email,
          message: this.message
        };``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210946/discussion-between-abdulazeez-olanrewaju-and-renaud-tarnec).